# Is there any difference between "[Only/All/All] that I need is"?

Tags: adverbs

Is there any difference between:

- Only I need is
- All I need is
- All That I need is

I noticed that this phrase is used with nouns after "is", can I use this phrase with verbs?

for example:

> Only I need is sleeping/working etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt's advice is good but to answer your question:
"Only I need is" is wrong. It could be said "The only thing I need is".
For example,
"The only thing I need is sleep".
That means, I need sleep and nothing else.
These 3 phrases can be used in almost the same situations but consider:
"Do you want a drink?"
"No, the only thing I need is sleep." 
"All I need are just 10 more votes and I've won"
"Do you need anything else?"
"No, I have all that I need right here"
You would never use a verb after any of these phrases.